# Conditional statement issues

Tags: conditionals, ifelse, image-galleries

**EE v2.4.0** (Updating is not an option at this time)

Hello! The photo gallery that we use still shows up even when no photos are added. Basically what I'm trying to do is get the image gallery to show only if a user uploaded an image. I've done this type of thing before on 2.9.2, but for some reason (I suspect a version issue) it's not working.

Here is the original code:

```
        <div class="left article_image">
          <ul data-orbit>
          {article_images}
                <li>
                  <img src="{image_matrix_image}" alt="">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <p>{image_matrix_cutline}<em>  ({image_matrix_byline})</em></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
            {/article_images}
          </ul>
       </div>
```

And here is what I've added:

```
     <div class="left article_image">
       {if article_images}
          <ul data-orbit>
          {article_images}
                <li>
                  <img src="{image_matrix_image}" alt="">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <p>{image_matrix_cutline}<em>  ({image_matrix_byline})</em></p>
                  </div>
                </li>
            {/article_images}
          </ul>
          {if:else}
          {/if}
       </div>
```

So you see, what should be an easy task, is just not working. **The result is both an empty album *not* showing and an album with images *not* showing.** How big of a newbie am I and what am I missing? I have tried moving around the ifs and ifelses. I have also tried using '== true'.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

[image: Here is what it looks like when a user does not add an image in ExpressionEngine and posts the article. The gallery slider still shows up.]

Picture of empty image slider above.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your code correctly, you use Matrix field to keep images. Try next code for this:

```
 <div class="left article_image">
   {if article_images:total_rows>0}
      <ul data-orbit>
      {article_images}
            <li>
              <img src="{image_matrix_image}" alt="">
              <div class="caption">
                <p>{image_matrix_cutline}<em>  ({image_matrix_byline})</em></p>
              </div>
            </li>
        {/article_images}
      </ul>
      {if:else}
      {/if}
   </div>
```

Comment: Hmm I seem to be getting a parse error when I try this. I've also played around with it some more and all have failed. I've also tried {if article_images:total_rows >= 0}

 But, this total_rows attribute seems like it's the obvious way to go. Thank you for your help, I'll keep pluggin' away!

Comment: try to use it this way   {if "{article_images:total_rows}">0}

Comment: As a string, really? Interesting. I tried this and fortunately no parse error, but still no change. Empty image slider still weirdly shows up. Edit: I didn't mean for this to sound offensive if it did, sorry! haha

Comment: I'm starting to think it's the matrix, I'm comparing the edit field in the backend from 2.40 to 2.9.2. And it looks like in the 2.4.0 backend the matrix 'add image' row is ALWAYS there (cannot delete) as opposed to the 2.9.2 where you have to ADD a new image row. I'm wondering if this is the problem?

Comment: for string you can use {if "{article_images:total_rows}" != "0"} but question is - what html code you have now for empty images? Do you have everything what inside <li></li>?

Comment: Tried just now, no change. Yeah what you see is what I use, that's the HTML I use for our image slider for posted articles. Of course it's also in another div or two for body article and such. And around that is the exp:channel:entries and closing. But I figured I wouldn't need to post that? It's A LOT of code. It's weird since I've used image matrix before in newer versions and have never had a problem there, which is why I'm starting to believe it's a version issue? Who knows.

Comment: is this site online? send me message to max at eec.ms